# func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) segfault

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11

I'm attempting to take a picture that I will later send to a restful service.  Will debugging I discovered that when it exits the imagePickerController function a segfault is generated.

The code looks like:

```
 extension ViewController{
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: 
    UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])  {
        let selectedImage: UIImage? = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage

        let originalImage: UIImage? = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
      let imageData:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImage!)!
          let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedData()
          if let smallShoeImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage!, 0.1) {
        print ("smallShoeImage = ", smallShoeImage)
        SendImagetoML(shoeImage: originalImage!)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}//imagePickerController

func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    view.alpha = 1.0
}
} //extension
```

If I commented out everything in the imagePickerController it still generates a segfault.

Here's the segfault:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3mtY.jpg

The segfault occurs when you leave the imagePickerControllerDelegate function but it seems to capture the image and I can use it later but I think the segfault should not occur.

My class definition looks like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, LoginButtonDelegate{
  var picker = UIImagePickerController()
```

As far as I can tell, everything is proper but I get the segFault when I leave imagePickerController so I must have missed something.  I also tested with:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
```

but that is the delegate for earlier versions of Swift and if I use it, it is never called.  iOS 11 with XCode 9.1 (Version required for iOS 11 had to upgrade).

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by learning how to safely and properly work with optionals in Swift. Every use of `!` means "crash here if I'm wrong".

Comment: You only get the "crash here" if the optional you are unwrapping with the exclamation point is nil.  That doesn't happen here.